# Software to manage guest WIFI access by creating random usernames and passwords?

Tags: passwords, wifi

I'm the administrator of a growing corporate network and we will shortly be providing guest WIFI access.

I have been to various places before where the receptionist has generated a random username and password which has then given me access to the web for a period of hours. If I wanted more, I'd go back to reception and they'd repeat the process.

I would like to implement a similar process for our network.

Does anyone have any pointers towards suppliers/makers of the software that could do this? I imagine it'd run on a Windows PC, and connect to our Active Directory in order to create such accounts under the appropriate policy.

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on serverfault or superuser. It isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of routers have the ability to communicate to a Radius server.  What you would need is a front end to generate usernames and passwords for the radius server that expire after X amount of time.

Comment: Agree - I was just hoping there was an out-of-the-box piece of software available rather than having to build something custom.

Comment: http://freeradius.org/dialupadmin.html  googled radius management applications.  this was in the top 3.